# What is cluster situation with respect to sand mining?

Tags: minerals, rivers, environmental-protection, mining, ore

> **Guideline on handling cluster issues :** The original Environmental  Impact Assessment ( EIA ) notification does not provide for the procedure to handle cluster situation, which has been proposed in this guideline and will become part of the notification. One EIA will be prepared for one cluster irrespective of number and size of mining leases in that cluster, if the area is more than 5 hectares.

Taken from a book am reading on Environment, the author isn’t internationally known but I will still mention his name, Shankar.

Answer (score 1):

Cluster in this situation refers to a grouping or a number of mining operations within a giving area.

Sometimes deposits of minerals with sand deposits is such that a number of smaller deposits is created instead of one larger more continuous deposit. When this happens it sometimes makes more sense to mine the deposits as separate pits instead of one large pit. The result is a cluster of mines within a given region/area.

Comment: Thank you. The picture is now clear to me.